# Is there a way to send push notifications only to the lock screen?

Tags: ios, user-interface, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to send many push notifications to users (about 1 a second, to every user). I only want these push notifications to appear on the lock screen (and each new notification replaces the previous one... i.e. coalesces with apns-collapse-id) and not the home screen.

I want to achieve a "live ticker" effect, but only on the lock screen.

The reason I don't want it to appear on the home screen is because it would be very intrusive to the user while he's doing other things on the iPhone.

That said, I would *also* like to send to the home screen, if possible. Sometimes. For example, when a user gets a private message, I would like to be intrusive and show the banner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically control where or when a user receives a push notification.  That setting is controlled by the user in the app-specific settings, not the app itself.

[image: App Notification Settings]

I also do not believe that sending one push a second is a scalable solution.  You don't have control of when a user gets a push notification, and pushing that frequently would likely cause Apple to throttle your notifications.